# Store number of a dropdown menu as an integer AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I have a dropdown menu that has numbers in it. The menu is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <label>Choose number</label>
        <select ng-model="visitors_list" id="visitors">
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="1">1</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="2">2</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="3">3</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="4">4</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

My goal is to store the desired number as an integer based on my selection. For example, if I choose 2, then the number 2 would be stored as an integer in variable.
Is there any way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should be what you are looking for,
In the html add an event to your selector like this (the $event will retrieve the selected value):

```
<select ng-model="visitors_list" id="visitors" (change)="onSelect($event)"> 
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="1">1</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="2">2</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="3">3</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="4">4</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

And in your typescript:

```
export class YourComponent {

  selectedNumber!: number; // Create a variable called selectedNumber and set it to null.


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}


/**
 * The function takes an event as an argument, and sets the selectedNumber property to the value of the
 * event's target.
 * @param {any} event - any - The event object
 */
  onSelect(event: any) {
    this.selectedNumber = event.target.value;
  }

}
```

And now you can use your  variable as you wish, I hope I helped you